# Can't install TL-WN821N (V5) drivers on Kali

Tags: kali-linux

I'm trying to install the drivers to my wireless adapter ([TL-WN821N version 5](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN821N_v5)):

I have already tried the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtl8192eu-dkms
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package rtl8192eu-dkms
```

I have also tried manually downloading and installing it, but I'm getting this:

```
make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.6.0-kali1-amd64/build M=/root/Desktop/20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.6.0-kali1-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:1323: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

edit: lsusb output

```
root@kali:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c0e Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
**Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2357:0107**  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should upgrade your kernel version then install the `linux-headers`:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Or install the latest `linux-image` and `linux-headers` .

You can get the list by :

```
apt-get update
apt-cache search linux-image
```

Then install the latest one (replace `linux-image-xx` :

```
apt-get install linux-image-xx
apt-get install linux-headers-xx
```

Reboot (to boot the latest installed kernel)

Install the required package:

```
apt-get install git build-essential
```

Install the wifi driver

```
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make
make install
```

Reboot