# I can't install TP-LINK TL-WN821N v5 driver on kali kernel 4.9.0

Tags: drivers, kali-linux

Inform

```
uname -r
```

Kali Rolling 64-bits

```
4.9.0-kali3-amd64
```

I have troubles at the `make` step while installing the driver

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.9.0-kali3-amd64/build M=/root/rtl8192eu-linux-driver  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.9.0-kali3-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

On the official website of TP-LINK, they said this device don't support in kernel v4.9.0. So I need your helps to fix this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Try this answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348777/cant-install-tl-wn821n-v5-drivers-on-kali

Answer (score -1):

Try to use:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-amd64
```

Comment: Answers that begin with _try to_ are not answers but comments.

Comment: It sounds uncertain, but seems to me like is has a chance of solving the problem.